# MacBook Pro Retina SLOW boot on Mojave

Tags: boot, mac, sleep, kext

This is my first post and I wanted to know if anyone else has the same issue as me - Current boot time with Mojave 1-2min.
My system is a Mac book Pro retina mid 2012 highest specs, ssd with a fresh installation of Mojave.
When booting in verbose I see where everything freezes.
It look like this:

```
HID: Legacy shim 2
AppleUSBMultitouchDriver: :checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2:
Warning: kexts unavailable; proceeding w/o lock for <unknown>
Warning: couldn't block sleep during cache update
Warning: proceeding w/o DiskArb
Warning: /AppleInternal/Library/Extensions: No such file or directory
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
HID: legacy shim 2
```

Any ideas?

[image: Verbose Pic]

Comment: You shouldn't have an AppleInternal folder. Find it & trash it. It's only needed if you're an Apple employee & enables some service-side info [nothing big & seekrit, just some extra reminders for customer-facing employees]

Comment: Thank u, I would if I new where it is. On other hand it says "No such file or directory" so why does Mojave boot looking for it? excuse my ignorance on this

Comment: It tells you where it is... it's right at the root level /AppleInternal Xcode will look for it, as will some other processes. If it finds one, then it will look what's in it. If it doesn't it should ignore it completely. My guess is the folder is there but not the contents. `Warning: kexts unavailable` also looks like something is being asked for in a startup plist which also isn't there.

Comment: Thank u again but (and excuse my lack of knowledge) I cannot find it at the root level of my drive. Moreover I don't have Xcode nor can download it from the Appstore as I m not a developer. Your guess is as good as mine on the Kext.

Comment: What are the first few log lines that print **after** the boot stall?

Comment: HID: Legacy shim 2

Comment: pcl pause: SDXC

Comment: followed by 6 lines of "spaceman_trim_free_block..." scan

Comment: bash: /etc/rc.server: No such file directory

Comment: taint: New update not compatible or older version: 2019a.1.0 vs 2019a.1.0: No such file or directory

Comment: Then continuing with several normal lines, meaning no apparent error and continues with

Comment: some other lines showing failures and errors like "configureInterests - nElements <= 0!Failed to configure interests". "Failed to addSubscription to group interface" as well as few other errors probably due to usb devices connected at the time (I have tried this without having them connected already)

Comment: Sorry few comments up should read: "tzinit: New update not compatible or older version: 2019a.1.0 vs 2019a.1.0: No such file or directory –"